# Android dexguard: Multiple problems have occured?

Tags: android, eclipse, dexguard

I am getting the following error when trying to install `DEXguard` onto a simple application within `Eclipse`:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Optimizer and Obfuscator (DexGuard)' on project 'test'.
com/android/sdklib/util/GrabProcessOutput$IProcessOutput
```

This error occurs when I try to run the app.

Also all of the other projects in my Ecipse have the `red exclaimation mark erro`r, what is the issue here?

EDIT: I removed the red exclaimation mark error but removing Android dpendencies from the build path, however the original error is still persisting when I attempt to run the project.

Comment: You installed the dexguard plugin via /dropins folder in the DexGuard getting started guide?

Comment: Yes I have done that?

Comment: the error is occuring every time i open eclipse

Comment: Could add some logs to the question? workspace/.metadata/.log You might also mention the version of eclipse, Dexguard, android sdk. According to DexGuard 6.0.24 docs you need Eclipse (version 3.7 or higher) with the plugin of the Android Developer Tools (version 23.0.1.1256982 or higher)

Comment: same situation got here- i am using dexguard 5.4 .17 and eclipse Juno and using android 4.1.As soon i try to run my application -i will get same message as he describes above.                                                        I installed the dexguard plugin via /dropins folder in the Eclipse.but earlier it was working fine.

Comment: Please tell me how to resolve that ??

Comment: can it be possible due to license expired ??

Answer (score 1):

Such an error is a sign that you're combining the DexGuard plugin with an incompatible version of the Android plugin in Eclipse. You should check the compatible version numbers that are documented in the DexGuard manual. Upgrading both plugins to the latest versions should work.

Comment: -getting same error as above.please  tell me how to resolve that ??

Comment: can it be possible due to license expired of dexguard??

Comment: No, DexGuard doesn't stop functioning, but the Eclipse plugin of DexGuard 5.4.17 is probably not compatible with the latest Android plugin. You should compare the plugin versions that you have installed in Eclipse with the plugin versions that are documented in the DexGuard manual.